# Add/Remove item from array - javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

I was wondering how I can add/remove item to array depending on if it's already in there.

Basically, I have a list of items and every item has their own ID, I want to add it or remove it depending on if it's already in the basket array and indicate (with css) if it's already in there.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What you have tried so far?

Comment: What have you tried? post some code. https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: This is the kind of thing you should really be able to Google. 'How do I add an item to an array', ' How do I check if element exists in array'...

Answer (score 0):

You can use jQuery built in function `$.inArray`

```
cart = ["value1","value2","value3","value4"];  // Cart Items
var new-item = "value2";
var index = $.inArray(new-item, cart);

if(index == -1){
    // Item doesn't exist. Add this item to the cart
    cart.push(new-item);
}else{
    //Item already exists.
    //Delete that item.
    unset($array[index]);
}

console.log(cart); //Display the cart items.
```